# ng-repeat on select is overriding content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this code:

```
<select>
    <div class="arrow-up"></div>
    <option data-ng-repeat="x in y">{{x}}</option>
</select>
```

the output hides the arrow div like:

```
<select class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <option data-ng-repeat="x in y">x1</option>
    <option data-ng-repeat="x in y">x2</option>
</select>
```

Is that a built-in operation or i am missing something?
Thanks

Comment: You need to use ngOptions 

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: `select` can only have `option`or`optgroup` as child element

Comment: yes, thank you guys, i tried the first solution, it still hides my element.

Comment: Why don't you put an option tag with the class?

Comment: I guess i will just stick with the standards. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [official documentation of `<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) you can only declare `<option>` and `<optgroup>` tags inside it. A quote from docs.

> **HTML select `<select>` element**
>
> **Permitted content:**    Zero or more `<option>` or `<optgroup>` elements.